# Generate a select list of sundays in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hey All, 
I am using Rails 3 and the Chronic gem (for date parsing) and need to create a select list of Sundays for the past 6 months. Here is what I have so far:

```
<%
  # weeks in 6 months = 26
  week = 1
  sunday = Date.parse( Chronic.parse('this sunday').to_s )
  sunday_array = []
  while week <= 26
    sunday_array << sunday - ( week * 7 )
    week += 1
  end
%>
<%= select_tag 'sunday', options_for_select( sunday_array ) %>
```

Does anybody know a better / cleaner way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can play code golf with...

```
sunday = Date.parse( Chronic.parse('this sunday').to_s )
sunday_array = []
26.times { |i| sunday_array << sunday - ( i * 7) }
```

And then get rid of your magic numbers....

```
NUM_SUNDAYS = 26
sunday = Date.parse( Chronic.parse('this sunday').to_s )
sunday_array = []
NUM_SUNDAYS.times { |i| sunday_array << sunday - ( i * 7) }
```

And obviously, you would move it into a helper method so it's not sitting in your ERB. :)

Comment: Thanks Drew. I did have to make NUM_SUNDAYS lowercase, but it worked.

Comment: If you like an answer, consider up voting the answer (by pressing the arrows) and if you feel this is the best answer for your question, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check box. This lets other people know your question has been answered and they don't need to worry about it anymore. :)